# Getting selected item's Value and Text from bounded DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

My DropDownList is bound with `public List<SelectListItem> CountryList { get; set; }` Model's property as `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryCode, Model.CountryList, "-- Select --")`. `CountryCode` is a `short` property to hold the code of the Country. How can i achieve

1- Show both Code and Name of the country in the DropDownList as `"CountryCode - CountryName"`

2- Receive both Code and the Name of selected Country as bounded to the Model passed to the Action. In other words, the type of the CountryCode is `SelectListItem` rather than `short`

**PS. No scripting**

Answer (score 0):

> 1- Show both Code and Name of the country in the DropDownList as
>   "CountryCode - CountryName"

Got help from [Creating a DropDownList helper for enums](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2010/05/21/asp-net-mvc-creating-a-dropdownlist-helper-for-enums.aspx). Now the DropDownList is showing items as `0001 - Country Name` but it is not keyboard friendly because end user should type `0001` to select `Country Name` rather than typing `cou...`. And selected Text has to be parsed to separate Value and Text, though not end user's headache but not ideal.

**Working and waiting for the answer of second question...**

Comment: i think custom model binding would be helpful